# laravel pathing in link

Tags: laravel, hyperlink, path

I am using same thing but result is different. In posts.blade.php  i can call like this

```
<a href = "posts/{{post->id}}"edit>Edit</a>
```

But when i use same thing in rooms.blade.php indisde rooms folder i had to use like this.

```
<a href = "{{$room->id}}/edit" class = 'btn btn-primary'> Edit</a>
```

It is really confusing me. Any solution? i want to add link for editing post inside room. I have tried many things but i dont understand.

My Route

```
 Route::get('/','PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/services', 'PagesController@services');
Route::get('/register', 'PagesController@register');
Route::get('/logout', 'PagesController@logout');
Route::get('/posts', 'PostsController@posts');
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
Route::resource('rooms','RoomsController');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

Comment: What is your route code

Comment: I edited post check

Comment: Did you placed room.blade in sub folder room

Comment: In post.blade the code really worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the name of the route

Foe example:

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', 'PostController@showPost')->name('post.show');
```

And then call the blade

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.show', [$id]) }}">Link to Resource {{ $id }}</a>
```

Comment: This works but i dont understand why these two are being different.

Comment: Okay i solved my problem. It was mather of slash /rooms/{{room->id}}/edit is working fine

Comment: @JaniBoLd I do not understand why you should use it

**<a href="{{ $room-> id }}/edit "class = 'btn btn-primary'>Edit</a>**

you could create a route

**Route::get('/room/{id}', 'RoomController@editRoom')**

And then the link would look like this:

**<a href="/room/{{ $room->id }} "class = 'btn btn-primary'> Edit </a>**

Comment: But creating custom function in Controller not working for me. 
can you please answer this question if possible?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710175/custom-function-in-controller-with-resource-wont-work