# Custom function in Controller with resource wont work

Tags: laravel, controller, custom-function

I have created my own custom function in my RoomsController

```
public function join($id){ 
    return $id; 
}
```

Then I want to pass variable to it and it says MethodNotAllowedHttpException
And my Form looks like this

```
{{Form::open(['action'=>  ['RoomsController@join', $room->id], 'method' => 'POST' ])}} 
{{Form::submit('Join', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
{{Form::close()}}

Also have these routes


Route::get('/','PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/services', 'PagesController@services');
Route::get('/register', 'PagesController@register');
Route::get('/logout', 'PagesController@logout'); 
Route::get('/rooms/join', 'RoomsController@join'); 
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
Route::resource('rooms','RoomsController');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

I have tried in many different ways i dont know why it is not working. All update edit destroy resource functions are working. Thank's for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're submitting a `POST` request but the route is expecting a `GET` request. If you change your route to `Route::post('/rooms/join', 'RoomsController@join');` it should work

Comment: It worked but still getting error 
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\RoomsController::join()

Comment: Okay i figured it yout thank you route should me Route::post('/rooms/{room}/join', 'RoomsController@join');  in order to pass variable

Answer (score 0):

change the method to post and put the route below the resource route

```
Route::resource('rooms','RoomsController');
Route::post('/rooms/join', 'RoomsController@join');
```